# validation.pem contains false instead of private key

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to bootstrap using custom template. Here is my bootstrap command I am using

```
knife bootstrap 1.2.3.4 -t D:\chef-starter\chef-repo\.chef\bootstrap\chefbootstrap-linux.erb -x root -P XXXX -N chefclientrhel -r "recipe[starter]" -j '{"bootstrap_directory":"/etc/chef/prod/prov","chef_client_package":"/tmp/chef-13.6.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm","instance_id":"12345-678910"}'
```

and here is my template with relevant code. There are some other pieces of code not relevant to this issue , hence skipped.

```
bash -c '
<%= "export http_proxy=\"#{knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy]}\"" if knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy] -%>

<%# Get bootstrap command-line attributes (from -j flag) -%>
<% if @config[:first_boot_attributes]['chef_client_package'] -%>
chef_client_rpm="<%= @config[:first_boot_attributes]['chef_client_package'] %>"
<% else -%>
chef_client_rpm="/etc/chef/chef-11.12.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"
<% end -%>

<% if @config[:first_boot_attributes]['bootstrap_directory'] -%>
<% bootstrap_directory = @config[:first_boot_attributes]['bootstrap_directory'] -%>
<% else -%>
<% bootstrap_directory = "/etc/chef/chefdefault" -%>
<% end -%>
bootstrap_directory=<%= bootstrap_directory %>            

awk NF > <%= bootstrap_directory %>/validation.pem <<'EOP'
<%= validation_key %>
EOP
chmod 0600 <%= bootstrap_directory %>/validation.pem

<% if @chef_config[:encrypted_data_bag_secret] -%>
awk NF > <%= bootstrap_directory %>/encrypted_data_bag_secret <<'EOP'
<%= encrypted_data_bag_secret %>
EOP
chmod 0600 <%= bootstrap_directory %>/encrypted_data_bag_secret
<% end -%>

<% # Find the trusted_certs directory relative to the directory containing
# the config_file (knife.rb). Use the first *.crt file from that directory. -%>
<% cert_path = Dir[File.dirname(@config[:config_file]) + "/trusted_certs/*.crt"][0] -%>
<% cert_file = cert_path[cert_path.rindex('/')+1..-1] -%>
echo Writing server cert file <%= cert_file %> to trusted_certs...
mkdir -p <%= bootstrap_directory %>/trusted_certs
cat > <%= bootstrap_directory %>/trusted_certs/<%= cert_file %> <<'EOP'
<%= ::File.read(cert_path) %>
EOP
echo Server cert file written.

<% #customize client.rb file, e.g. specify log file and level etc, replace original input for var config_content -%>
<%  
client_rb = config_content
client_rb.gsub!(':auto',':info')
client_rb.gsub!("/etc/chef" ,bootstrap_directory + "/")

puts client_rb
-%>

cat > <%= bootstrap_directory %>/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= client_rb %>
ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer
log_level  :info
<%= "client_key \"" + bootstrap_directory + "/client.pem\""  %>
<%= "validation_key \"" + bootstrap_directory + "/validation1.pem\"" %>
<%= "http_retry_count 5" %>
<%= "http_retry_delay 5" %>          
<%= "rest_timeout 300" %>

<%= "require \"" + bootstrap_directory + "/SuccessReport.rb\"" %>
<%= "require \"" + bootstrap_directory + "/FailureReport.rb\"" %>
<%= "report_handlers << SuccessReport::RunningResults.new" %>
<%= "exception_handlers << FailureReport::RunningResults.new" %>
EOP

<% # Double any backslashes to solve Linux-only problem where half are getting lost on way to first-boot.json -%>
cat > <%= bootstrap_directory %>/first-boot.json <<'EOP'
<%= first_boot.to_json.gsub('$','\$').gsub('\\', '\\\\\\\\') %>
EOP

<% # customize to sub out the old bootstrap directory -%>
<%
new_start_chef = "/usr/bin/sudo -n " + start_chef
new_start_chef.gsub!("/etc/chef/" ,bootstrap_directory + "/")
new_start_chef.gsub!("-j" , "-c " +bootstrap_directory + "/client.rb -j")
-%>
echo <%= new_start_chef %>
<%= new_start_chef %>'
```

Every time I get the following error when I bootstrap

```
ERROR: The file /etc/chef/prod/prov/validation.pem or :raw_key option does not contain a correctly formatted private key.
```

when I open validation.pem it has `false` in it. That's all. I am not sure why this it is so. On my chef server I had created the org using the following command

```
chef-server-ctl org-create my 'For customer my' --association_user user1 --filename my-validator.pem
```

I tried cpoying my-validator.pem file to /etc/chef directory on chef server and renaming to validation.pem  but still it is not copying the correct validation file on client. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured out the issue. The issue was neither knife.rb nor the bootstrap command had validation_key. After Adding validation_key to knife.rb I got the validation.pem file on my node correctly. Though I am still getting 401 error while bootstrapping.